# partial derivative of a function defined between manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry

I know the definition of derivative of a map $\phi : M \to N$ defined between manifolds but i am willing to know that how the partial derivative of $\phi : M \to N$ will be defined? I know the definition of partial derivative if $N = \mathbb{R}$.

Also, i am not able to see that what would be the geometric interpretation of the partial derivative of a function between manifolds? We know that in multivariable analysis partial derivative represents  just the directional derivative with respect to  a coordinate axis.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by partial derivative? Can you also state in your question how it is defined when $N = \mathbb R$?

Comment: If $f: M \to \mathbb{R}$ is a $C^1$ function defined on a manifold $M$ and $(U,\phi; x^1, \cdots, x^n)$ is a coordinate chart around a point $p \in M$ then we define $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(p) = \frac{\partial (f \circ \phi^{-1})}{\partial u_i}(\phi(p))$ where $u_1, \cdots, u_n$ are the natural coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no meaning of partial derivative of your function. But if you want to discuss the differentiability of $f$ we use the following process.
Suppose that $U$ is a neighborhood of a point $p\in M^m$ and $V$ is a neighborhood of $f(p)\in N^n$. Also let the charts on $M$ and $N$ are $(\rho,U),(\sigma,V)$ about both $p,f(p)$ respectively. Then the function $f$ is called differentiable if the function
$$\sigma^{-1}\circ f\circ \rho:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$$ is differentiable.